# Short story about African missionary couple losing his mind, making mud statue

Tags: identification-request

My mom remembers reading a short story published in a college anthology at least before 1980, she thinks it was her father's so maybe published 30's or 40's. It was about a missionary couple to Africa and the man going insane/tribal, the wife giving him back the wedding ring and leaving him, and specifically the man making a mud statue that incorporated the wedding ring. We confirmed that she is NOT thinking of the Poisonwood Bible.